# Connect emergency button to arduino

Tags: arduino, switches, button

I need to connect this kind of button to my Arduino for a project :

http://www.ebay.com/itm/NC-N-C-Emergency-Stop-Switch-Push-Button-Mushroom-Push-Button-4Screw-Terminal-KG-/172356802290?hash=item28214416f2

This one is 600V, so I guess I cant connect it to the 5V of my arduino.
I don't know if if fits....
Do I need an external battery? How to wire it?

The other option is to self-build a button with one of these connectors : http://www.automation24.fr/commande-et-signalisation/element-de-contact-etroit-eaton-180792-m22-fk10-i132-3060-0.htm

What do you think?

Thanks ;)

Comment: < It's 600V. is it rated 600v or it generates 600v signal?

Comment: 600V/10A is the contact rating. That means the maximum voltage and current you can run through it. It doesn't magically turn 5V into 600V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just switches - you connect them to an Arduino as you would any other switch.  You will probably need a pull-up resistor, unless the Arduino has internal pull-ups that you can enable.

Answer (score 0):

The 600V rating on that switch is the *maximum* voltage that the switch can be used with. (The same thing goes for the 10A rating.)

You can hook this switch up to your Arduino just like any other switch. You don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

Switches rated to handle 600V will often not be suitable for TTL level circuits, at least not reliably. They are open to air and will eventually build up a resistive film on the surfaces. Opening and closing contacts generally burns that film off, but at 5VDC there is not enough energy to do so. For TTL level circuits, you need to find a button that uses what are called "reed switches" as contacts, or gold flashed contacts.